# My app has no dynos running - No web processes running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Some of my apps at heroku has no dynos anymore, although previously it worked fine:

[image]

heroku logs says `No web processes running`. My other applications are working well.

How do I fix it?

Comment: What does your `Procfile` look like for that app? Does it even have one?

Comment: @ChrisPeters, my other apps don't have it, are you sure the rails app have to have it?

Comment: Rails apps don't necessarily need a `Procfile`. But Rails apps deployed onto Heroku apps may. Why don't you try it?

Comment: @ChrisPeters, see my previous comment.

Comment: Yes, I saw your previous comment. Sometimes when you push an app to Heroku you're on a different version of a stack than your other apps. Sometimes that version of the stack works differently. I'm just suggesting something to try.

Answer (score 0):

i was having the same problem it really sucks i'm stuck in it from like 3 hours or more, eventually it's fixed just by deleting the whole heroku app and then specifying the buildpack that you gonna use in your interactive terminal with this command line `heroku buildpacks:set heroku/php` and you can add it on creating the app directly and that's what i did and it was fixed like that:

`heroku create myapp --buildpack heroku/php`

and the main reason was because of one python library has been installed i wasn't even using it so heroku finds two builpacks python and php and used the python one so when i did specifying that i'm actually using PHP everything has been pretty fine.